# LINQ Query - nearest adjacent date

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to write a method that will determine the closest date chronlogically, given a list of dates and a target date. For example, given a (simplified) date set of {Jan 2011, March 2011, November 2011}, and a target date of April 2011, the method would return March 2011

At first, I was thinking of using LINQ's skip, but I'm not sure of an appropriate Func such that it would stop **before** the date was exceeded. This below seems a viable solution, but I'm not sure if there's a more efficient means of doing this. Presumably Last and First would be linear time each.

The source dataSet can be between 0 and 10,000 dates, generally around 5,000. Also, I am iterating over this whole process between 5 and 50 times (this is the number of target dates for different iterations).

```
// assume dateSet are ordered ascending in time.
public DateTime GetClosestDate(IEnumerable<DateTime> dateSet, DateTime targetDate)
{
   var earlierDate = dateSet.Last(x => x <= targetDate);
   var laterDate = dateSet.First(x => x >= targetDate);

   // compare TimeSpans from earlier to target and later to target.
   // return closestTime;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, using [`MinBy`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/d987f0ef30390a9b66d5cc608e5e39648d26097a/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs) from [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ):

```
var nearest = dateSet.MinBy(date => Math.Abs((date - targetDate).Ticks);
```

In other words, for each date, find out how far it is by subtracting one date from the other (either way round), taking the number of `Ticks` in the resulting `TimeSpan`, and finding the absolute value. Pick the date which gives the smallest result for that difference.

If you can't use MoreLINQ, you could either write something similar yourself, or do it in two steps (blech):

```
var nearestDiff = dateSet.Min(date => Math.Abs((date - targetDate).Ticks));
var nearest = dateSet.Where(date => Math.Abs((date - targetDate).Ticks) == nearestDiff).First();
```

Comment: Without MoreLINQ, the same arithmetic can be used with some other LINQ expressions: `return dateSet.OrderBy(date => Math.Abs((date - targetDate).Ticks).First();`

Comment: I'd rather not pull in MoreLINQ as a dependency, but seems like a nifty project. Your and esker's responses have given me what I've needed. Thanks.

Comment: @esker: That will do it - but it requires O(N) memory and O(N log N) time, instead of O(1) memory and O(N) time. It's fundamentally inelegant, IMO :) But yes, it may well be all that's needed...

Comment: @Skeet, what are you saying is "O(1) memory and O(N)"? Your solution, or using MinBy?

Comment: @Stealth: Both of my solutions.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on determining Big O Notation. Your alogrithm would take O(2n) time, right? It has to go through the list once to gt the nearestDiff, and then again to find the nearest element?
I'm assuming N Log N for esker's answer is coming from the OrderBy Clause. LINQ's ordering takes n log n?

Comment: @Stealth Rabbi: O(2n) == O(n), just with a different constant factor.

Answer (score 1):

Using Last and First iterates the dateSet twice. You could iterate the dateSet yourself using your own logic. This would be more efficient, but unless your dateSet is very large or enumerating the dateSet is very costly for some other reason, the little gain in speed is probably not worth writing a more complicated code. Your code should be easy to understand in the first place.

Comment: The source data set can be between 0 and 10,000 dates, generally around 5,000. Also, I am iterating over this whole process between 5 and 50 times (this is the number of target dates for different iterations).  I'm adding this to the description

Answer (score 0):

It is simple!

```
List<DateTime> MyDateTimeList =....;
....

getNearest(DateTime dt)
{
   return MyDateTimeList.OrderBy(t=> Math.ABS((dt-t).TotalMiliSeconds)).First();
}
```

Comment: Please see the discussion below the accepted answer, indicating why this is not an improvement and should in fact be discouraged.